# C# constructor initializing properties instead of fields?

Tags: c#, constructor, properties, field

Let's say that you have to use an constructor to initialize some fields...

```
class Foo
{
    private int price;
    public Foo(int price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

I know that usually the constructor initializes some fields but what's the difference if I initialize properties with it. For example

```
class Foo
{
    private int price { get; set; }
    public Foo(int price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

The code seems to work the same but my question is if this is good practice and should I do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fine for a constructor to initialize properties, but it's *rarely* useful to have private automatically-implemented properties. I'd always use properties rather than fields for *non-private* state (whether those properties are automatically implemented or not) and private properties make sense when they're non-trivial, e.g. performing validation or some other computation. But I'd only turn a private field into a private automatically-implemented property if I wanted it for something like a reflection-based library that only understood properties.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely fine.

For more flexibility (e.g. if price isnt *required*), you can also do this with object initialization:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo() {}

    public int Price { get; set; }
}

var newFoo = new Foo(){ Price = someVariable };
```

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680.aspx